# Static route not working in CentOS 7.6

Tags: centos7, static-routes, iproute

UPDATE:

There was nothing wrong with the OS. The gateway for the static routes had some double NAT rules which caused the traffic to be dropped.

I have a simple network setup on a CentOS server. The server has only one interface:

**ifcfg-eth0:**

```
IPADDR=85.15.17.156
PREFIX=23
GATEWAY=85.15.16.1
DNS1=85.15.16.20
DNS2=85.15.16.21
```

and here is what it shows for **ifconfig**:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 85.15.17.156  netmask 255.255.254.0  broadcast 85.15.17.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe10:1c67  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:10:1c:67  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2374071  bytes 726672271 (693.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 339562  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 84906  bytes 19020154 (18.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 74123  bytes 9265792 (8.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 74123  bytes 9265792 (8.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have setup two static route as below:

**ip route:**

```
default via 85.15.16.1 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
85.15.16.0/23 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 85.15.17.156 metric 100
94.182.76.0/22 via 85.15.17.254 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
94.183.76.0/22 via 85.15.17.254 dev eth0 proto static metric 100
```

But I don't seem to be able to get to the gateway (85.15.17.254) when I try to ping an IP in one of those subnets:

```
[admin.local@server ~]$ tracepath 94.182.76.2
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  no reply
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
```

I can ping and ssh the gateway (it's a firewall):

```
[admin.local@server ~]$ ping 85.15.17.254
PING 85.15.17.254 (85.15.17.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 85.15.17.254: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.681 ms
64 bytes from 85.15.17.254: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.707 ms
```

EDIT 1:

There is route from the gateway to the end host:

```
ASA# sh run int
!
interface Port-channel1.299
 nameif Outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 172.31.74.3 255.255.255.0 standby 172.31.74.4
!
interface Port-channel2.62
 nameif Inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 85.15.17.254 255.255.254.0 standby 85.15.17.253

ASA# traceroute 94.182.76.2

Type escape sequence to abort.
Tracing the route to 94.182.76.2

 1  172.31.74.1 1 msec 1 msec 1 msec
 2  10.163.19.11 1 msec 1 msec 1 msec
 3   *  *  *
 4  94.182.19.252 210 msec 209 msec 214 msec
 5  94.182.76.2 209 msec 209 msec 289 msec
```

firewalld on the server is disabled. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The router probably isn't configured to route.

Comment: @womble The route is there. See my edit note